# How to move all filenames in current directory that are not pdf (contains spaces)?

Tags: sh, zsh

Right now, I have:

```
mv "$(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | grep -v '.pdf')" SomeFolder/
```

I am using `zsh` on MacOS. Filenames may contain spaces. I'd like to move all those that are not a pdf file. The current issue is that this does not correctly deal with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
setopt extendedglob
mv -v ^*.pdf(.) SomeFolder/
```

- `setopt extendedglob` - enables the `^` negation and other patterns for this session. Many users put this into `~/.zshrc` so that extended glob is always on.
- `^*.pdf` - all entries that are not `*.pdf`. `zsh` can handle file names with spaces here; no quoting is required.
- `(.)` - glob qualifier to limit the expansion to regular files. Equivalent to `-type f` in `find`.
- `-v` - verbose, just so it's obvious which files have been moved.

There's more information about negating glob patterns [here](https://superuser.com/a/774192/). You may also want to look at `zsh`'s very, very useful [`zmv`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/zsh/zsh-65/zsh/Functions/Misc/zmv.auto.html) [utility](https://blog.smittytone.net/2021/04/03/how-to-use-zmv-z-shell-super-smart-file-renamer/).

Answer (score 0):

Try use `mv` in a loop:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v '.pdf' | while read file; do mv "$file" SomeFolder/; done
```